# setting alpha value to ImageView

Tags: android

I am using the following code to set the alpha value of an ImageView (this should be compatible with all devices, even pre API 11)

```
AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.85F, 0.85F);
alpha.setDuration(0); // Make animation instant
alpha.setFillAfter(true); // Tell it to persist after the animation ends
ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.transparentBackground);
view.startAnimation(alpha);
```

However, when I open the app on devices running on gingerbread and below, the imageView is completely transparent but on devices running on honeycomb or higher, the alpha value is set to .85 and the imageView is displayed perfectly.

How can make this happen on gingerBread as well?

Answer (score 2):

An easy way to get this to work is to use the NineOldAndroids project which ports the Honeycomb animation API back to older versions including AlphaAnimation. See http://nineoldandroids.com/.

So, using the ObjectAnimator would be something like this:

```
ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(imageView, "alpha", .85f).start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a function to do it (has been deprecated because of the new view's generic way of handling transparency but can be used safely on Android 2.x):

```
myImageView.setAlpha(128); // range [0, 255]
```

You'll have to implement a custom animation though. This can be done with a handler for instance:

```
Handler animationHandler = new Handler() {
   public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
       int currentAlpha = msg.arg1;
       int targetAlpha = msg.arg2;

       if (currentAlpha==targetAlpha) return;
       else {
           if (currentAlpha<targetAlpha) --currentAlpha;
           else ++currentAlpha;

           imageView.setAlpha(currentAlpha);

           sendMessageDelayed(obtainMessage(0, currentAlpha, targetAlpha), 10);
       }
   }
}


// Show imageview
animationHandler.sendMessage(animationHandler.obtainMessage(0, currentAlpha, 255));

// Hide imageview
animationHandler.sendMessage(animationHandler.obtainMessage(0, currentAlpha, 0));
```

- Above code is not memory-leak safe (handlers should be static and should keep weak references to context and views
- You should improve it to allow controlling animation speed, ...
- You need to keep current alpha around because imageView does not have a getAlpha method.

Comment: How to make the custom animation? Can you give an example

Comment: See edited answer. You should have all you need. Now you got to experiment, correct above & improve it.

Comment: I thought `setAlpha(duration)` was not available until API level 11?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets create an custom imageview, it solves the problem , by overriding the onDraw :)

AlphaImageView.java

```
package com.example.shareintent;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AlphaImageView extends ImageView {

    public AlphaImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public AlphaImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public AlphaImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.saveLayerAlpha(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight(), 0x66, Canvas.HAS_ALPHA_LAYER_SAVE_FLAG);
        super.onDraw(canvas);
    }

}
```

your activity xml

```
<com.example.shareintent.AlphaImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
```

Comment: i get an error saying - The method setAlpha(int) from the type ImageView is deprecated

Comment: it didn't work. It sets the ImageView as opaque on every device

Comment: Ok, ifound the solution by creating custom imageview.